# Book recommendations for the mathematics in epidemiology

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

I would like to educate myself in a proper way about the terminology, concepts and mathematics of epidemiology. So instead of scrambling through separate articles on various websites, I would like to have at least one good written source. Moreover I am looking for the latest/"hottest" reference available, since albeit the mathematics has hardly changed, the examples could be more relevant in more recent sources. I am specifically looking for an insight into epidemiology from probabilistical/analytical point of view.